# Windows Machine File Copy: I am getting system error 1312 for powershell while deployment process through TFS

Tags: tfsbuild

I have installed TFS on my webserver, I have configured the build process in TFS to copy files to IIS directory on checkin.

I am getting below error. Is it because my TFS server and webserver is same?

Failed to execute the powershell script. Consult the logs below for details of the error.
Failed to connect to the path \{ipaddress} with the user Administrator for copying.System error 1312 has occurred.
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/windowsfilecopyreadme

please help, I have tried googling this first but couldn't get solution.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  TFS should live separate from any target web application server.  Why would you do this?

Comment: why is it so please? I have backup service in place in case of server crash so I don't see any problem here

Comment: What if you want to deploy to two servers or to Azure?  You can't install TFS on each server.

Comment: Agree, I won't need to do so for now, but my concern is with above issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned "Windows Machine File Copy", I assume you are using vNext build system.

"Windows Machine File Copy" is usually used to copy files to remote machines. Since your TFS Server and WebServer is same, I would recommend you to use "Copy Files" task and check "Over Write" option to copy the files to IIS directory. This will be more convenience.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Eddie, I am using team foundation server 2015, I don't see this Copy Files option http://screencast.com/t/lPqBFKxu
Is this something I will have to install extra? thanks for your help

Comment: @girishkolte Oh~Then you need to download the agent tasks from https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks and install it via tfs-cli:https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli. However, since the files is just copied from one place to another place in the machine. You can also create a powershell or batch script in build task to copy them.

Comment: I tried the cmd to copy files, it shows success but its not actually copying files, http://screencast.com/t/lZTzvOS0O

Comment: @girishkolte I didn't have any issue with xcopy sourcefolder targetfolder /E /Y. However if you want /X and /K, you need to set your build agent to run as Administrator.

Comment: thanks I figured the issue, I had to grant access to the TFS user in order to access and write files :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems your task host requires a specified logon session, you need to add domain username. Try to modify the Admin Logon to `<Domain or hostname>\ < Admin User>`.

Comment: thanks for reply, server is not added to any domain, I tried adding hostname\Administrator user but still getting the same error.

Comment: Just want to double confirm with you the error happened on Windows Machine File Copy step, correct? Could you share your setting of Windows Machine File Copy step? Try to use UNC share for the Source and Destination Folder to see whether you can copy the files.

Comment: Yes, here is the log http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cc5n4pa49
thanks
All I want to do is, copy the files checked in through TFS to iis directory, without performing the build (as I am working on website not application)